# Android programming spinner swap elements of spinner

Tags: android, spinner

**need to do so when you click on a specific button (application type translator and arrow key) changed one of the selected items to another spinner itam swapped Well, here is how it can be implemented? 
here is the code but it does not work!**

```
int spinner1Index = spinner.getSelectedItemPosition();
                spinner.setSelection(spinner2.getSelectedItemPosition());

                spinner2.setSelection(spinnerfirst);
```

**can offer something similar or fix!**

Answer (score 0):

You would have to change the adapter of your spinner and call `notifyDataSetChanged()`

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest adding this to your switch case for when the item is selected. 
Set a custom adapter for the spinner on item click.

//An array of what you want to populate the spinner with
Array spinnerArray [] = {"One", "Two", "Etc.."};

```
ArrayAdapter<String> spinnerArrayAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(
        this, android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item, spinnerArray);
spinnerArrayAdapter.setDropDownViewResource( android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item );
```

//Before setting the adapter, clear and notify the previous ArrayList used

```
      arrayList.clear();
      arrayList.notify();

spinner.setAdapter(spinnerArrayAdapter);
```